# Image testing accuracy increases after adding noise

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, svm

Im doing an experiment using facial images with  different aspects. First dataset are just normal faces, my second dataset are oclusions generated by just adding different levels of noise. First dataset is composed of noise added with a variance of 0.025, the second dataset has images with variance of 0.05. The third dataset has images with variance of 0.1. So, i trained and tested them using Linear SVM, where level of variance, i was expecting the test accuracy to go down. When i test with normal face images, the test accuracy is: 96.59 for normal face images, 48.04 for images with simulated oclusion, 95.01 for variance value of 0.025, 93.65 for variance value of 0.05. Everything looks reasonable until this point, however for a variance of 0.1 im getting 95.46 which is higher than image noise with variance of 0.05.

I was expecting the last value to be lower than 95.01.

I am using the same model for every dataset training:

```
SVC(kernel='linear',  C=0.00006)
```

I wonder why is such thing happening and whats a reasonable fix? Given that i'd like to use the same regularization parameter to train every dataset.

How i am adding noise to the image in percentage levels:

```
    def generate_noisy_image(x: np.array, variance: float) -> np.array:
        noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=variance, size=x.shape)
        return x + noise

    def load_dataset(path, max_num):
        imagesList = listdir(path)
        loadedImages = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for i, name in enumerate(files):
                if i == max_num:
                    break
            print(image)
            img = PImage.open(path + image)
            img.resize((81, 150))
            arr = np.array(img)
            noise_image = generate_noisy_image(x = arr, variance=0.1)
            noise_image = Image.fromarray(noise_image)
            noise_image = noise_image.convert("L")
            loadedImages.append(arr)
            #noise_image.save('C:/Users/Noise-Dataset/Noise_Value_10/'+person_folder+filepath, 'JPEG')
        return loadedImages
    
    
    noise_dataset_1 = load_dataset('C:/Users/Noise-Dataset/Noise_Value_10', 50) 

    X_train_n1, X_test_n1, y_train_n1, y_test_n1 = train_test_split(
            noise_dataset_1_array, noise_1_target, test_size=0.49, random_state=0)


def train(clf, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print ("Accuracy on training set:")
    print (clf.score(X_train, y_train))
    print ("Accuracy on testing set:")
    print (clf.score(X_test, y_test))
    
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    
    print ("Classification Report:")
    print (metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print ("Accuracy:")
    print (metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

svc_1 = SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.00006)
train(svc_1, X_train_n1, X_test_n1, y_train_n1, y_test_n1 )
```

Comment: All the accuracies you report are close enough so that the differences *may* be just statistical flukes, especially if your test set is relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this before, and augmenting the images actually increased accuracy. Here I'm assuming you are doing a classification task, say gender detection? The reason behind your results is that your original facial images might have different degrees of noise within the prediction class (for example, most male images are noisy and female images are less noisy), so when detecting the output, the model uses low-level cues, i.e. noise as a feature. You can think of the model as being 'lazy' and especially here you are not using DNN so it might be more likely that the model was 'lazy' and relying on low-level cues. By adding noise, you make it harder for the model to rely on the information because all images are now noisy so the model starts to look for high-level cues which in your case might be provide the model higher prediction power/accuracy.